# Why does infinity behave strangely?

Tags: haskell, enums, lazy-evaluation, infinite

I've created natural numbers the usual way.

```hs
data Nat
  = Zero
  | Succ Nat
```

And I'd like to make them an `Enum`. Now when I make them an `Enum` I want them to be maximally lazy. I'm primarily using `Nat` for the lengths of lists fully evaluating a `Nat` usually means fully evaluating a list, so

```
f x =
  [2 .. natLength x]
```

Shouldn't have to evaluate the whole list to know what its first element is, just the first two elements.

My litmus test for laziness is to use infinity.

```hs
infinity =
  Succ infinity
```

If it works with infinity is has to be lazy, because you can't evaluate all of infinity.

So I'm implementing `Enum`.  For this question I'm only concerned with `enumFromThenTo` which I've defined as follows:

```hs
instance Enum Nat
  where
    enumFromThenTo =
      go Zero
      where
        go n (Succ x) (Succ y) i =
          go (Succ n) x y i
        go n Zero y i = do
          j <- i - y
          (y +) <$> (n : go n Zero y j)
        go n y Zero Zero =
          n : do
            m <- n - y
            go m y Zero Zero
        go n y Zero i = do
          v <- (n + y) : go n y Zero Zero
          (+ i) <$> (v - i)

        x - Zero =
          [x]
        Succ x - Succ y =
          x - y
        Zero - Succ _ =
          []
```

I can include my `Num` instance upon request, but it's not very interesting.

This works just like I want it for all finite values, but doesn't work for `infinity`.  However it doesn't break in the way I'd expect.  I'd expect it to stall out and not halt with `infinity`, but it doesn't. It halts, but with the wrong answer, and I don't know why.

```
ghci> take 14 [1, 9 .. 100]
[1,9,17,25,33,41,49,57,65,73,81,89,97]
ghci> take 14 [1, 9 .. infinity]
[9,17,25,33,41,49,57,65,73,81,89,97,105,113]
ghci> [100, 9 .. 0]
[100,9]
ghci> [infinity, 9 .. 0]
[9]
ghci> [6, 100 .. 7]
[6]
ghci> [6, infinity .. 7]
[]
```

All the finite values produce the correct input, but when `infinity` is involved it seems the first value is dropped.  I can't tell why though.  Especially since there shouldn't be a way to tell `infinity` from an arbitrarily large number.  I can bump the numbers up really large and it works just as fast and doesn't make the error.

```
ghci> take 4 [1,2 .. 100000000000000000000000]
[1,2,3,4]
ghci> take 4 [1,2 .. infinity]
[2,3,4,5]
```

Why is this happening?  This seems utterly bizarre to me.  Can anyone step me through the execution and show what's wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: Actually, in `take 14 [1, 9 .. 100]`, the list is defaulting to type `[Integer]`.  Try `take 14 [1, 9 .. 100] :: [Nat]` instead.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Ah jeez.  Wow that's so obvious now that I see it.